# How to create three function with same name one is callback, second is promise other is async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, npm, mongoose

I want to create a function which can be utilised in 3 ways for creating npm dependency

1. Promise way
2. callback way
3. async/await way

**For Example**

**1) async/await**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
async function Connection() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongourl');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Connection error --->", err);
    }
}
Connection();
```

**2) Callback Style**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongourl', function (err) {
    if (err) console.error("Connection error --->", err);
});
```

**3) Promise Style**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongourl').then(() => {

}).catch(err => console.error("Connection error --->", err));
```

Did u absorve that **mongoose.connect** is same name for all types

Comment: `Promise way` & `async/await way`   Are both the same thing from a user point of view.

Comment: And to make it so it's the same name, just check if you a parameter been sent, if you do use callback way, if not return a promise.

Comment: As for the callback/promise: you can just check the type of the second argument and set the logic accordingly. Please see Mongoose [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/8f3463450265e927596420a32caa1c2c4bb5f1d6/lib/connection.js#L411) for openUri function (connect() is a wrapper for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, it's similar to @hsz, but I've put the handling for the inner callback.

If your pass a callback it does this in a callback way, if not it returns a Promise instead.

If you run the snippet you can see it in action.
I've basically created a simple setTimeout function that randomly fails, to show how error handling is also done.  So to see the full effect try running the snippet a few times.

```js
function doInner(name, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5)
      callback(null, "Did " + name);
    else callback(new Error("Oops in " + name));
  }, 1000);
}

function doSomething(name, callback) {
  if (callback) {
    doInner(name, (err, result) => {
      if (callback) callback(err, result);
    });
  } else return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    doInner(name, (err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(result);
    });    
  });
}


//now lets test both ways

doSomething("test callback", (err, result) => {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  else console.log(result);
});

(async function () {
  try {
    const result = await doSomething("Promise");
    console.log(result);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
const connect = (name, callback) => {
  try {
    const result = /* generate result */

    if (callback) {
      callback(null, result);
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(result);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (callback) {
      callback(e);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  }
}
```

And quick usage example:

```
connect('John')
  .then(result => { /* ... */ })
  .catch(error => { /* ... */ });

connect('John', (error, result) => { /* ... */ });

async function foo() {
  try {
    const result = await connect('John');
  } catch (error) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: `doSomething` is likely to be a callback method.  :)    So you may need to wrap in a `new Promise()`, not just a `Promise.resolve()`

Comment: Not really, callback is callback. I ment a function that gives result of the function.